# why fork() return double zero if we use it first in a if or while

Tags: c, linux

It's from my homework. In the code, there should be 2 processes, father and child. But in the code, there will be 2 zero, and will never get in the branch p1>0.
Here is a code. I use fork() and get double zero, it's confusing. I want to know how the fork() works in this code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "signal.h"
int k1;
void func1(int signo){
    if (signo==SIGUSR2)
    {
        k1=0;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int k,p1;
    while (p1=fork()==-1);//one time
    if (p1>0)
    {
        for (k = 1; k < 4; k++)
        {
            printf("parent:pid=%d\n",getpid());
            sleep(1);
        }
        kill(p1,12);
        wait(0);
        printf("OK!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        signal(12,func1);
        k1=1;
        while (k1==1)
        {
            printf("I'm child\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf("Child forced!\n");
        exit(0);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know how fork() works in this code.

The output of the code is loop output: "I'm child". Output two lines per second.

However, in my opinion, there should output "parent:pid=%d", but the code won't get in the "p1>0" branch. it seems that fork() generates 2 processes but all of them have p1=0.

Comment: Where is that code again? Not in the question, certainly.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the code, it' available now.

Comment: Can you edit the post and add the actual output, and then the output you expected?

Comment: I add the actual output. And the actual output in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in [operators precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `==` has higher precedence than `=` and thus `while (p1=fork()==-1)` is parsed as `while (p1=(fork()==-1))`. When You run this code `fork` succeeds and in both branches returns value different from -1. That's why in both, the child and the parent, `p1` is equal to 0 (false).

You need to add extra parenthesis around assignment: `while ((p1=fork())==-1)`.